# Why simple search doesn't work?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a simple search bar to search through my blog articles.
The problem is that when I search something on it nothing happens, it doesn't even reach the view where the pdb traceback should run.

If anyone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how `GET` should work to search queries it'd be really helpful.

here is all related code for the search bar :

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'articles': articles})

def search_articles(request):
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace() (doesn't get executed if uncommented)
    articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=request.GET['title'])
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"articles": articles})
```

**index.html**

```
<form role="search" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <button>Search</button>
</form>

{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article.title }}
{% endif %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^search/$', views.search_articles, name='search'),
```

I don't see any problem but somehow `GET` doesn't reach the view since the pdb debugger doesn't get executed. Any suggestion on where the issue might be ?

Comment: `the search bar doesn't work` isn't very descriptive, can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: is that all your urls.py? Changing the order of the /search to first one changes anything?

Comment: @joaoricardo000 Solved, the problem came from here. I can't believe how basic it is, but I thought since the search view was at the end of the urls, it'd override the first one.

Comment: Changing the order solved because you have overlaying URL pattern definitions. Double check your regex to make sure you do not have any unexpected behavior. Glad to help!